# Insert new line after number

Tags: vbscript

I have the below code in my text file.

```
Consumer Extract |: 10684 Campaign Extract |: 13018 Survey Response Extract |: 73300 Fullfillment Extract |: 220003
```

Now, is there any way that new line gets inserted after we find number. I want to get the output file as

```
Consumer Extract |: 10684
Campaign Extract |: 13018
Survey Response Extract |: 73300
Fullfillment Extract |: 220003
```

Answer (score 0):

Add vbCrLf to your string once you find the number. Eg:

```
var = "string 1" & vbCrLf & "string 2"
MsgBox var
```

will display a message box showing

```
string 1
string 2
```

Comment: but how can i find a number in the code (given above) and add vbCrLf? Any pointers please

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegExp that finds non-empty sequences of digits followed optionally by whitespace and replace the matches with CrLfs added:

```
>> s = "Consumer Extract |: 10684 Campaign Extract |: 13018 Survey Response Extract |: 73300 Fullfillment Extract |: 220003"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "(\d+\s*)"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "$1" & vbCrLf)
>>
Consumer Extract |: 10684
Campaign Extract |: 13018
Survey Response Extract |: 73300
Fullfillment Extract |: 220003

>>
```

**Update wrt comments:**

If you don't know how to get the contents of a file, consult the [horse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: i am getting the below error 'VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'r.Replace''

Comment: i got the result. but is there any way to read the data from the file rather than setting it as '>> s = "Consumer Extract |: 10684 Campaign Extract |: 13018 Survey Response Extract |: 73300 Fullfillment Extract |: 220003"'